# get rid of FormData in Next.JS backend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, next.js

I simply would like to repeat this guide: https://medium.com/@_hanglucas/file-upload-in-next-js-app-router-13-4-6d24f2e3d00f for uploading files using Next.js, but the line `const formData = await req.formData();` throws error, it says `Error [TypeError]: req.formData is not a function`, although autocomplete of Visual Studio Code displays, that such method exists `(method) Body.formData(): Promise<FormData>` and there is no error.

Since this is the `TypeError`, I updated `next, react, typescript` and `@types` related to it to `@latest`, but still have this error.

Any ideas why is it so? Maybe there is another `@types` I must install?

**Versions:**

"next": "^13.4.4",
"react": "^18.2.0",
"react-dom": "^18.2.0",
"typescript": "^5.1.3",
"@types/node": "^20.2.5",
"@types/react": "^18.2.8",
"@types/react-dom": "^18.2.4"

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're using next js pages router (you have pages folder)
To use formData on the server you need to use new app router (next 13+) https://nextjs.org/docs/app